# how to remove spaces above and below a line using anisble

Tags: ansible

I have following playbook which added the line correctly after the regex match, but there is a empty line added above and below the new line that is added. How do i remove the empty line above and below in ansible

```
- name: updating sdf_known_hosts/tasks/main.yml
   blockinfile:
     path: ~/Desktop/main.yml
     insertbefore: '^\s*-\s"test'
     marker: " "
     block: |3
            - "{{ server_name }},{{ new_server_ip }} {{ server_key }}"
```

Comment: Please anybody help me on the above query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the marker added by the `blockinfile` module.

Use `lineinfile` module, if you don't want the marker.

```
- name: updating sdf_known_hosts/tasks/main.yml
  lineinfile:
    path: ~/Desktop/main.yml
    insertbefore: '^\s*-\s"test'
    line: "    - \"{{ server_name }},{{ new_server_ip }} {{ server_key }}\""
```

Comment: lineinfile will remove the space but the indentation is not maintained. Can the above be used with blockinfile since the indentation should be maintained

Comment: You can use indent in lineinfile also. Updated my answer.

Comment: yes, that works. But I need the output in the follwoing format

Comment: Variables should be enclosed within the double quotes in the output. When blockinfile is used the expected result is got but there are spaces above and below

Comment: you can escape those and add here. updating the answer.